# Split Packages: Java Modules vs Sealed Jars

Tags: java, jar, java-module

Both Sealed Packages/Jars and the Java Module System disallow spliting packages across several jars.
Does that mean that all packages contained within a Module are implicitly sealed? If not what does explicitly sealing the jar change?

Comment: I suppose sealing packages means the no-split-packages enforcement will also work if your code is placed on the class-path. The module-info descriptor, and the associated stricter rules, is only used if the module is placed on the module-path.

Comment: I believe the Sealed attribute in manifests is ignored in a modular .jar.  Package.isSealed() will return false in such cases, even though the package is conceptually sealed.

Comment: You know by chance wether that is specified in the specs somewhere? Sounds like a rather odd design choice if that is indeed the case

Comment: @VGR the Sealed attribute is indeed ignored for modular jars, however, the outcome is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, packages within modules are always implicitly sealed. This is specified in [the documentation of the `Package` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html):

> A `Package` automatically defined for classes in a named module has the following properties:
>
> - The name of the package is derived from the [binary names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) of the classes. Since classes in a named module must be in a named package, the derived name is never empty.
> - The package is sealed with the [module location](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReference.html#location--) as the code source, if known.
> - The specification and implementation titles, versions, and vendors are unspecified.
> - Any annotations on the package are read from `package-info.class` as specified above.

I also made a quick test to verify that `isSealed()` on a module’s package did indeed return `true`. However, it must be noted that the relationship between (named) modules and packages is of a fundamental nature and hence, independent of the fact that `isSealed()` returns `true`. The latter is just the natural way for the old API to interact with this new feature.

A sealed package of an unnamed module only affects the runtime package of the particular class loader, as each class loader can have a package of the same name, which is considered a different runtime package.

In contrast, each package of a named module must unambiguously belong to a single module within the entire module layer and a module layer can span multiple class loaders, e.g. the [boot layer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#:%7E:text=A%20Java%20virtual,creating%20additional%20layers) spans the bootstrap loader, the platform loader, and the application loader.

This affects the class loading process. The old way of loading, which is still used for the unnamed module, features class loader delegation where each loader queries its parent loader first. When the parent loader failed, the class path entries are queried linearly for the class until a class is found.

When a module layer is initialized, all package names and their owning modules are recorded, so when an attempt to load a class is made, the package name can be derived from the qualified name and mapped to a module even before the class is loaded and therefore, only the module’s known source needs to be queried.